# How to apply filter on different key values of Objects which are in array in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I am trying to apply a filter to an array that has objects and I want get results as if I type country or name or value in the search bar and get results of that specific query-related.
Kindly help me how can I achieve. Currently, I'm able to get results either of one value not all but I want to any of the queries can give results.
Here is my Array:

```
 data: [
    { id: "1", value: "Zaid Qureshi", country: "Pakistan", price: "23" },
    { id: "2", value: "Wasiq Safdar", country: "UK", price: "23" },
    { id: "3", value: "Bilal Hasan", country: "US", price: "23" },
    { id: "4", value: "Waqas Hasan", country: "Austria", price: "23" },
    { id: "5", value: "Malik Mati", country: "Saudia", price: "23" },
    { id: "6", value: "Zeeshan", country: "Japan", price: "23" },
    { id: "7", value: "ABC", country: "China", price: "23" },
    { id: "8", value: "DEF", country: "Isreal", price: "23" },
    { id: "9", value: "GHI", country: "Canada", price: "23" },
    { id: "10", value: "JKL", country: "Inda", price: "23" },
  ],
```

Currently I'm doing this

```
 const searchData = this.state.data.filter((item) =>
      item.value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const searchData = this.state.data.filter((item) =>
  item.value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
  item.country.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || 
  item.price.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);
```

You can make it more dynamic so that each time you add new key-value, you don't need to modify the logic again by putting another OR

```
let searchData = data.filter((item) =>{
  for(key in item)
  {
   if(item[key].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
   {
      return true
   }
  }
  return false

}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to use the OR operator.

A quick highlight on operator : && logic (AND) - || logic (OR).

```js
const searchData = this.state.data.filter((item) =>
  item.value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) 
||
  item.country.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) 
|| 
  item.price.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);
```

good luck in your project